# OpenCV SVM "unsupported response type" error

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I use the following code to train an opencv svm:

```
cv::SVMParams params;
cv::SVM svm;

params.svm_type = cv::SVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = cv::SVM::LINEAR;
params.term_crit = cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);

svm.train(trainData, trainLabels, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), this->params);
```

where `trainData` is:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> data;
// Do stuff and fill data vector

cv::Mat trainData(data.size(), data.at(0).size(), CV_32FC1);

for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < data.at(0).size(); ++j)
        trainData.at<float>(i, j) = data.at(i).at(j);
```

and `trainLabels` is:

```
std::vector<unsigned> labels;
// Do stuff and fill labels

cv::Mat(labels);
```

but I have this error:

> C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp:675:error: (-210) Unsupported response type in function cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses

which I never seen before and couldn't find when I searched.

Comment: Are you asking what it is, or why it's there, or how do you fix it?

Comment: @VeniVidiVici I guess all of them but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is function `cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses`?

Comment: @VeniVidiVici Probably it's opencv's function since I don't have this function nowhere in my code

Comment: Are you using VS, or what?

Comment: @VeniVidiVici Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Why downvoted? What's wrong?

Comment: When you write the question, start with IDE and IDE version (or editor), compiler, and OS. Don't make people read through the code before they get to the bug, because they'll have to reread everything again. I don't particularly want to do that. You also did not really ask a question; you just said what happened. If you had asked this question less than 24 hours earlier, it probably would have been closed as unclear. With a question like this, the community does not really want to spend the time on it.

Comment: @VeniVidiVici Sorry, but if you don't want to spend time on this just pass it and let someone else help me.

Comment: I'm working on it. I'm just saying that it's not my favorite pastime. If you can edit the question to include those things, I will remove my down vote.

Comment: What is line 675? Is that in the code you've shown?

Comment: @VeniVidiVici No, it's from opencv

Comment: Are you using any variables, functions, classes, or anything that you did not specifically write?

Comment: Another vital detail that is easily overlooked: did the error appear as window or in a build/run log? That is probably the most important.

Comment: Okay, I am stupid. The problem is that labels can't be type of `unsigned int`. It turns out it only `int` is supported. I changed to `int` and it works.

Comment: Can answer your question so everyone can see exactly what you did?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking to close the question since nobody really cares. Should I answer it?

Comment: How about that person a year down the road that can't find anything else out there? Besides, how can you say nobody? Am I nobody?:) I'm certainly curious.

Comment: Well, nobody except you :) You 're right, I will answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was actually very simple. `cv::SVM` just doesn't support `unsigned int` type for labels, changed it to `int` and it works perfectly.